# DOMDocument Incorrect Syntax was used in a comment

Tags: excel, domdocument, xmlhttprequest, vba

I'm writing a "quick" scraper in excel, but I can't load the XML from Wall Street Journal. I'm getting the error message "Incorrect Syntax was used in a comment" from this code.

```
Dim xmlReq As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set xmlReq = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60: Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.resolveExternals = True
xmlDoc.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", False

With xmlReq
    .Open "GET", "http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3023-cashprices-20150101.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar", False
    .send ""
    Debug.Print .statusText
    If Not xmlDoc.LoadXML(.responseText) Then
        Err.Raise xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmlDoc.parseError.reason
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

I'm assuming this is because there's a "--" in the WSJ's xml, but is there any way I can suppress this error?

I normally would do this through a COM Add-in, but I'm only grabbing two Cash Prices, so it's not worth the hassle. Maybe it is?

Comment: ehh...loading that URL up in Explorer does not give me any XML. Perhaps that's your issue?

Comment: Ah. I was getting an xPath of two items I'm looking to scrape, so I had assumed I could have retrieved them that way. Am I doomed to try to sort through the HTML unserialized?

Comment: Nevermind on this - I can get the data through C# and HtmlAgilityPack. Just need to deploy an Add-In is all.